# Asking for user consent during first app launch with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, launching-application, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

Which is the best way to ask for user consent (for personalized ads, analytics etc.) during the first app launch with Xamarin.Forms?

Should a new ConetentPage get created for this purpose or is there another way to implement the consent settings?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion.  You could just display a dialog as part of your main page, or you could display a separate page.  It depends on your requirements and how much data you need to display as part of the process.

Comment: Is the only method for opening a dialog the `DisplayAlert` method? If yes, I guess I can't use it, because I want to implement checkboxes for each service separately and I don't think that's possible with the aforementioned method.

Comment: You could display a page modally, or there are other packages that will allow you to display custom dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate page or page modal could be used. In the display alert we have limitations, we cannot have our own custom content, I personally use the below library, so I can have my page show as a pop-up. Please check this

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: A new ContentPage is what I chose as a solution. I'm not interested in installing extra packages in order to present it as a pop-up though. No need to bloat the up for a something that will be shown to the user once.